# How can I cast an existing Moose object into an extending instance?

Tags: perl, moose

I have a Moose class named 'Child' which extends another class named 'Person'. Given a 'Person' instance I would like to create a `Child` instance.

How can I cast the existing 'Person' into a 'Child', without explicitly creating a new `Child` and passing each of the arguments from `Person'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Class::MOP::Class::rebless_instance`](http://p3rl.org/Class%3a%3aMOP%3a%3aClass#rebless_instance)